# Blender for Chromebook

Tags: system

How would I be able to run Blender on a Chromebook? The Rollapp is a farce that demands money for free software, and the whole reason I didn't buy a windows laptop is because I hate Windows 10, so is there another option?

Comment: I hear Chromebooks will soon support regular Linux apps, if they don't already, which might help there. But I think this question is off topic here.

Comment: https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/08/19/install-linux-applications-chrome-os/ ... all You need to know buddy.

Comment: has anyone actually done this successfully?

Comment: @pluke yes.  I replied with an answer below.  Works for me just fine.

Comment: great! I'll give it a go

Comment: First off, don't use a chromebook; most are too underpowered for blender. get a laptop that's actually capable. system76 should fit your needs right off the bat : https://system76.com/laptops | but I recommend finding a cheaper alternative and install a Linux distro to it (Manjaro,Pop_OS!,Solus,Debian,Ubuntu,ect.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hate Windows 10, there are other options. I know you asked about Blender on Chromebook, but you can find non-Windows 10 computers for very cheap or free. I got a desktop with Linux from my local library, and my tech teacher gave me a Windows 7 laptop for free. Try asking around.

Comment: IMO Chromebook is a good alternative to a linux laptop (even though it's still in beta).  ChromeOS does a lot of the heavy lifting for you and you get the benefit of linux apps and terminal.  I've posted an alternative answer if you want to critique the steps I used to install blender on my chromebook.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a chromebook and was interested in this very topic.  I've compiled the correct steps from [this link](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/08/19/install-linux-applications-chrome-oss) as well as some basic exploration.

1. Hit the Launch button (key with a small circle on the left side of the keyboard where caps-lock is on other keyboards) and type "terminal".  I was prompted to accept the linux install and I did.
2. Update packages (this had a couple of errors when I ran it that I ignored.. I *think* the failures are updated by chrome OS in the background in its distro that it maintains for you).

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

3. Install gnome and update it with these commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-software gnome-packagekit -y
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

4. Restart your Chromebook
5. Hit the Launch button again, and search for "Software" and open it.
6. Search for blender, then install it.

It should now appear in your Launch menu alongside your other apps.  Gnome also gives you a launch button when it's finished installing.

Comment: What version of blender is this?

Comment: The .79 release for me. Not sure when the linked apt-get source will update to use the .8* versions

Comment: The repos seem very slow at keeping up to date. It's be interesting to see which chrome books can handle the higher spec requirements

Answer (score -1):

If you're going MAC, make sure you get a newer model. Several years ago, my Dad got an all in one iMac with a decent Nvidia Card, which he recently learned is nearly useless. How? **Apple dropped Cuda Support**. Just wanted to warn you guys.

I recommend checking out [Concierge Render](https://www.conciergerender.com/) by Coreweave. It's a large render farm for Blender projects, available to the public. It can run images and animations in 2.79, 2.8 and 2.81 Cycles and Eevee in 2.81. Using it costs as low as 30 cents per gpu per hour, and you get $5 credit just for signing up.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure you can get Linux on chromebooks, but to install Blender I think you can check how to install it on Linux
https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en

Answer (score -2):

instead of using windows or Chromebook you could use Mac especially because they are built to be able to render the product.

Comment: Before you invest on a mac read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135986/blender-2-8-beta-no-compatible-gpus-found-on-imac-2018/135992#135992

Comment: Mac platform is often regarded as over priced, and it is a particularly poor choice for 3D modelling and rendering especially with Blender