# My AMD GPU is not available in Cycle Render Preferences on version 2.8

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, eevee-render-engine

I am using laptop with AMD Radeon HD 8670m GPU in it. I have latest drivers installed. But when I access Blender System Preferences it displays:

"NO COMPATIBLE GPU'S FOUND. CYCLES WILL RENDER IN CPU".

I used the same in 2.79 and I found  no problems. Please help me fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [this page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware) GCN 2nd generation is required by Blender 2.80, and according to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_HD_8000_Series) your GPU is GCN 1st generation. That's very likely the cause of your grief.

Comment: But this page https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ says "AMD: GCN 1st gen and newer", so...?

Answer (score 1):

Your graphics card doesn't meet the [requirements for GPU rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware) with Cycles as @DuaneDibbley already linked. The [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for the GPU are only for being able to run Blender at all.

For Blender 2.8 you will need GCN first generation or newer to run Blender. GCN second generation or newer is required for OpenCL GPU rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an ambiguous response, I am not familiar with the issue of Radeon and dedicated GPUs, it is not a personal opinion that I issue, this is the result of a quick search on the subject, it seems that your GPU is not compatible with 2.7xxx &
 2.8, but if it is compatible with previous versions

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that Mac users have been left behind with the arrival of 2.80 when the new manual says "AMD OpenCL GPU rendering in supported on Windows and Linux but not on macOS."
I have a Radeon Pro Vega 64 16 GB card on an iMac Pro and with 2.79 I get:
[image]

but with 2.80 I get:

[image]

Comment: Note that this is not an issue in blender. Apple has changed their support for OpenCL and changed to a proprietary code (metal). Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135992/1853 and https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20gpu%20apple%20metal&oq=blender%20gpu%20apple%20metal&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.9814j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8