# Blender 2.8 doesn't recognize my graphics card for GPU

Tags: osx, hardware

Blender 2.8 isn't recognizing my graphics card for gpu or opencl rendering. I'm using a mac with a Radeon Pro 580 8 GB graphics card. Are there any articles about best graphics card for use in Blender? I'm thinking about buying a new one, since the cpu rendering takes very very long. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I remember correctly, Apple dropped OpenCL support in favor of their new Metal api

Comment: @Dr.Farquaad - [that is correct](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135992/23985).

Answer (score 1):

Blender is only capable of doing GPU rendering on CUDA (NVIDIA cards) and openCL (originally develop by Apple & maintained by Khronos group)(1). However Mac dropped support for openCL(2) therefore there is no way to use an AMD GPU for GPU rendering on Blender nor other software that uses only openCL.

The only option, that I haven't tested is to try to use Linux on your machine and download AMDGPU-PRO from [AMD's website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-radpro-lin-16-40). No guaranteed to work.

1.- [GPU Rendering - Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#amd-opencl)

2.- [Apple Drops OpenGL and OpenCL](https://www.i-programmer.info/news/201-ios/11875-apple-drops-opengl-and-opencl.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me. I'll look into using Linux an downloading AMDGPUPRO. Do you know of any articles or forums that discuss graphics card options for mac w/ blender? Thanks